# Resque could not find job class ZF2 namespaces

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, php-resque

Attempting to use the Redis backed PHP-Resque project https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque from within a ZF2 project. (Apigility to be specific)

What I'm having trouble with, is combining the ZF2 namespaces and the classes

for instance :

**Controller**

```
    //Enqueue a worker

    $args = array(
        'name' => 'EMCP'
    );
    Resque::enqueue('default', 'phpresque\\V1\\Model\\MyResqueJob', $args);
```

**MyResqueJob Class**

```
namespace phpresque\V1\Model;

class MyResqueJob
{


    public function perform()
    {
        // Work work work
        echo "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

Error message given by resque :

```
 ubuntu@/zf2projectname/vendor/chrisboulton/php-resque$ QUEUE=* APP_INCLUDE=/zf2projectname/vendor/autoload.php VVERBOSE=1 php resque.php 

** [03:01:37 2014-10-26] Sleeping for 5
** [03:01:42 2014-10-26] Checking default
** [03:01:42 2014-10-26] Found job on default
** [03:01:42 2014-10-26] got (Job{default} | ID: 38fa104b11de81731c15ba9c2f1853ab | phpresque\V1\Model\MyResqueJob | [{"name":"EMCP"}])
** [03:01:42 2014-10-26] Forked 30642 at 2014-10-26 03:01:42
** [03:01:42 2014-10-26] Processing default since 2014-10-26 03:01:42
** [03:01:42 2014-10-26] (Job{default} | ID: 38fa104b11de81731c15ba9c2f1853ab | phpresque\V1\Model\MyResqueJob | [{"name":"EMCP"}]) failed: Could not find job class phpresque\V1\Model\MyResqueJob.
** [03:01:42 2014-10-26] Checking default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : I dropped using Resque but here's the suggestion below on how it could work.. I ended up using SlmQueue instead https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmQueue

According to the ZF2 github community, the following should be done :

Shouldn't your `APP_INCLUDE` environment var contain the path to composer's `init_autoloader.php`? Just including the autoloader class will not suffice, as you not configuring and registering the autoloader anywhere.

and

YMMV, but what I've done to integrate my ZF2 app into Resque is create a separate entry point script that initializes the ZF2 app within the context of the Resque worker:

```
<?php
// resque_context.php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$application = \Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
$config = $application->getServiceManager()->get('config');
```

And provide it's path to the Resque run script via the `APP_INCLUDE` environment variable.

Comment: hi @Erik can you please provide the final job class code? Have same issue and can't make it work

Comment: I put this as a suggestion, but in the end with the a different job queue entirely for ZF2.  SlmQueue to be exact.  Works swimmingly. https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmQueue